# How display content of a web page with a url in .onion using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

So , I try to display the content of a web page in .onion.

my code :

```
import requests
import urllib3



urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


a = requests.get('https://unhy7hu4mlew5suizw466o76xcsfv5oreft7kgupvcgvp4km56iu3wqd.tor2web.org',verify=False).text 

print(a)
```

This program give me no error, nothing.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

using socks5h will make sure that DNS resolution happens over the proxy. Try this code:

```
import requests

def main():
proxies = {
        'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
        'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}
r = requests.get('<url_here>', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thx you for your answer but i dont want use Tor proxy i want use a url with Tor2web do you know a way ?